# Как из дружественной функции наследуемого класса получить доступ к данным базового класса

Tags: c++

Есть базовый абстрактный класс и есть два наследуемых от него. В каждом наследуемым классе есть объявления дружественной функции которая принимает первым аргументом объект cout,а вторым ссылку на сам объект и эта функция выводит поля этого класса. Проблема в том,что функция может вывести поля только класса в котором она объявлена,а как тогда мне выводить поля базового класса? как решается такая задача?

вот базовый класс

```
class AcctDMA
{
private:
    char *label;
    int rating;
protected:
    char* get_label() { return label; }
    int   get_rating() { return rating; }  
public:
    AcctDMA(const char * l = "null", int r = 0);
    AcctDMA(const AcctDMA &rs);
    virtual ~AcctDMA() = 0;
    AcctDMA & operator=(const AcctDMA &rs);
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os,const AcctDMA & rs);
};
```

вот наследуемый класс

```
class hasDMA : public AcctDMA
{
private:
    char *style;
public:
    hasDMA(const char * s = "none", const char *l = "null", int r = 0);
    hasDMA(const char * s, const AcctDMA &rs);
    hasDMA(const hasDMA &hs);
    ~hasDMA();
    hasDMA & operator=(const hasDMA &rs);
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const hasDMA & rs);
};
```

вопрос был о последней функции в классе hasDma

вот её реализация

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const lacksDMA & rs)
{
    os << "color: " << rs.color << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

Пробовал делать так,не получается

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const lacksDMA & rs)
{

    os << AcctDMA::get_label << std::endl;
    os << AcctDMA::get_rating << std::endl;
    os << "color: " << rs.color << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Что-то вы нас обманываете. Дружественная функция принимает `hasDMA`, а реализация `lacksDMA`

Comment: А когда разберетесь где у вас какая функция, попробуйте `rs.get_label()`

Comment: Члены класса, объявленные как `private` недоступны в производных классах. `operator<<` дружит с производным классом и видит только то, что видит сам производный класс. Для доступа к закрытым полям используйте открытые или защищеные (в вашем случае) геттеры

Comment: Прошу прощения,я перепутал класс. Там есть lacksDMA, но там такая же проблема с дружественной функцией. Я пробовал способ через rs.get_label() но компилятор ругается. Единственный способ,который я вижу - это создание в наследуемом классе ещё одних защищённых методов,которые вызывают защищённые методы базового класса,но не будет ли это костылём или неправильным ходом?

Comment: Что такое `AcctDMA::get_label`? Функции в С++ вызываются при помощи оператора `()`. И не  `AcctDMA::get_label`, а  `rs.get_label()`. Вам нужно изучить основы языка. Также: описания в стиле "но компилятор ругается" тут бесполезны и никому не интересны. Приводите детальное описание того, что говорит компилятор.

Comment: Да,вы правы,забыл поставить оператор (),но даже при нём выскакивает ошибка "невозможно обратиться к protected член объявленному в классе AcctDMA".  Я попытался объявить в классе lacksDMA защищённый метод  -  char* get_bas_label() { return get_label(); }   но это дружественная функция не видит эту функцию

Comment: хорошо,спасибо за замечания. Я пересоздам тему и подробно опишу все ошибки